# Incorrect syntax near the keyword 'User'. error keeps popping up

Tags: c#, sql-server

Searched different solution but nothing worked. I have the same code for registering a user and it works fine, I can't find the problem in this code

```
SqlConnection sql = new SqlConnection(@"Data Source=(LocalDB) Security=True;Connect Timeout=30");
sql.Open();
cmd = new SqlCommand("INSERT INTO [MenuItem](User, Order1, Order2, Order3, VALUES(@User, @Order1, 
      @Order2, @Order3", sql);
        cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@User", label20.Text);
        cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@Order1", checkBox1.Text);
        cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@Order2", checkBox2.Text);
        cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@Order3", checkBox3.Text);
        cmd.ExecuteNonQuery();
        sql.Dispose();
```

Comment: Not an expert in C#, but I think it's wrong T-SQL syntax: `INSERT INTO [MenuItem] (User, Order1, Order2, Order3) VALUES (@User, @Order1, @Order2, @Order3)`.

Comment: ^^ Zhorov is talking about missing closing parens ")"... The error message is somewhat misleading because it complains about the opening `(` that have no matching `)`.

Comment: I added the parenthesis but the same error pops.

Comment: @Zhorov is correct, `(User, Order1, Order2, Order3,` you need to remove the `,` and add a `)` to enclose the column names. Also wrap `User` in brackets: `[User]` as its reserved. On another note, use `using` statements to dispose of your objects and use `Add` and specify the datatype, length etc.; not `AddWithValue` as it has to infer the data types.

Comment: Related - don't use [addwithvalue](http://www.dbdelta.com/addwithvalue-is-evil/)

Answer (score 1):

`USER` is a reserved keyword in T-SQL; avoid using it for object names. If you do, you must delimit identify it. (`[User]`).

You're also missing a right parenthesis in your SQL and have an extra comma: `...Order3) VALUES ...`

Answer (score 1):

I would quote the word user too:

```
cmd = new SqlCommand(@"INSERT INTO [MenuItem]([User], Order1, Order2, Order3) 
VALUES(@User, @Order1, @Order2, @Order3)", sql);
```

Generally advisable to avoid calling columns the same as reserved words (pretty much anything that highlights in SSMS) because it means you have to wrap the name in square brackets, and it's rather ugly

Answer (score 0):

Your error is in Syntax since you're missing a few `)`.

Take a look at this query example:

```sql
INSERT INTO Production.UnitMeasure (Name, UnitMeasureCode,  
    ModifiedDate)  
VALUES (N'Square Yards', N'Y2', GETDATE());
```

(See [other insert examples](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/t-sql/statements/insert-transact-sql?view=sql-server-ver15#InsertExamples))

Answer (score 0):

**Your error is just in the syntax of your query**.

This is the correct syntax for your SQL query:

```
INSERT INTO [dbo].[MenuItem] ([User], [Order1], [Order2], [Order3]) VALUES (@User, @Order1, @Order2, @Order3)
```

Just a little suggestion:

Even if you can avoid the "dbo" mention, use it, or your db will have to search for it.